# Hitbox detection in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I have a problem with checking if my character is hit in my XNA game.  I have a character class that contains a hitbox but how could i possibly make it check for other characters to be hit?

is there way to do that like this:

```
if(this.hitbox.Y = [any other character using this class].attackbox.Y)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is it not working or what? 
Remember it's: `if(x == y)`

Comment: this wont work because its a class for every character and every character should detect attacks from other characters

Comment: -1 Should not be so hard to search for this on google!

Answer (score -1):

As i understand "hit" is when hitbox1 has a non-empty intersection with hitbox2.
I'd suggest something like below (for a 2d hitboxes)

In XNA framework there's a method for it: `Rectangle.Intersects()`, so use it.

The manual way of doing it would look somewhat like decribed below:
Say, hitbox is a rectangle with coordinates [(x1,y1),(x2,y2)], then we got several alternative cases similar to the one below

```
if(h1.x2 >= h2.x1 && h1.y2 >= h2.y1)
{
    \\this is one of cases when we got hit
}
```

This is the way I'd do it.

Comment: Why not use `Rectangle.Intersects(<Rectangle>)` method?

Comment: Yes, that will definitely work :) I wrote it in my post, just didn't know the exact function name.